# Show custom popup over ActionBar's navigation icon

Tags: android, material-design

I found a Material design patterns for Android on this  link: https://ui8.net/product/material-ui-kit-cooking
There is a popup menu which I want to implement. I didn't find it in the Android SDK.
1. Which is the fastest method to create this popup?
2. How can I position this popup to overflow ActionBar's Navigation Icon?

[image: Popup menu]

Comment: Start off by trying to implement the `PopupMenu`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use thing like this

```
public class ListPopupWindowAppActivity extends Activity
implements OnItemClickListener {
EditText productName;
ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow;
String[] products={"Camera", "Laptop", "Watch","Smartphone",
    "Television"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_popup_window_app);
    productName = (EditText) findViewById(
        R.id.product_name);
    listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(
        ListPopupWindowAppActivity.this);
    listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(
        ListPopupWindowAppActivity.this,
        R.layout.list_item, products));
    listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(productName);
    listPopupWindow.setWidth(300);
    listPopupWindow.setHeight(400);

    listPopupWindow.setModal(true);
    listPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(
        ListPopupWindowAppActivity.this);
    productName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listPopupWindow.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    productName.setText(products[position]);
    listPopupWindow.dismiss();
}
}
```

keep custom adapter if you want to with custom row. Hope this helps to someone if yes let me know friends :)